# cryptsetup and passphrae restrictions

Tags: pam, luks, cryptsetup

I'm trying to encrypt a new HD to add to my Red Hat server. I have two other drives that are already encrypted with a passphrase. However, when I try to use the same passphrase on the new drive I get:

> Password quality check failed: The password contains more than 4 characters of the same class consecutively

I've tried disabling/commenting out `pam_pwquality` line item in both system-auth and password-auth in the `/etc/pam.d` folder with no luck.

Is there a way to disable this passphrase check temporarily to get this drive encrypted with the same passphrase as the other two drives?

Answer (score 0):

ok it turns out I had to use the --force-password switch